# Как в Yii2 связать длинный URL с действием контроллера?

Tags: yii2, yii

Не получается в Yii2 связать URL /user/confirm/email/resent с методом (действием) actionConfirmEmailResent контроллера UserController. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для действия `UserController::actionConfirmEmailResent()`, url будет - `user/confirm-email-resent` по умолчанию.

Если хотите именно `/user/confirm/email/resent` то измените в настройках параметр `rules` компонента `urlManager`:

```
...
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        ...
        'rules' => [
            '/user/confirm/email/resent'=>'user/confirm-email-resent'
        ],
    ],
    ...
```